# Prediction : Can`t load model "VGG16 model.h5" in system Weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm, h5py

*load model*

> "**model.load_weights(VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet'))**"

```
    VGG16=load_model('E:/TBirds/TBirdDOCS/PythonCode/DOCMODEL/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')

    # build the VGG16 network
    #model = application.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
    model.load_weights(VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet'))
    # get the bottleneck prediction from the pre-trained VGG16 model
    bottleneck_prediction = model.predict(image)
    #print(bottleneck_prediction)
```

ValueError: Cannot create group in read-only mode.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator.SQL6/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36/site-packages/keras/engine/Auto-AI.py", line 254, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Administrator.SQL6/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36/site-packages/keras/engine/Auto-AI.py", line 244, in main
    prediction_And_Bookmark(writer, Total_Number_of_Pages, pdf_source,File_Name)
  File "C:/Users/Administrator.SQL6/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36/site-packages/keras/engine/Auto-AI.py", line 189, in prediction_And_Bookmark
    layb, count, pos = predict(test_imag)
  File "C:/Users/Administrator.SQL6/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36/site-packages/keras/engine/Auto-AI.py", line 97, in predict
    VGG16=load_model('E:/TBirds/TBirdDOCS/PythonCode/DOCMODEL/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SQL6\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
    return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SQL6\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 584, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SQL6\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 270, in _deserialize_model
    model_config = h5dict['model_config']
  File "C:\Users\Administrator.SQL6\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py", line 318, in __getitem__
    raise ValueError('Cannot create group in read-only mode.')
ValueError: Cannot create group in read-only mode.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

> ValueError: Cannot create group in read-only mode.

Answer (score 1):

- **to download VGG16 model**

  ```py
  from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
  model=VGG16(include_top=False , weights="imagenet")
  ```
- **to load saved weights file "VGG16.h5"**

  - copy directory path which include file.h5

    ```py
    from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

    model_path='C:\\Users\\nourh\\.keras\\models\\vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'

    model = VGG16(include_top=False ,weights=model_path)
    ```

> windows 10 , tensorflow 1.14.0

Answer (score 0):

If you saved weights and architecture separately and trying to load weights using `model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')` then you will get `ValueError: Cannot create group in read-only mode`.

Which means that you are trying to load the weights of the model without its architecture.

To over come this issue, you can you can save both weights and architecture in one go as .h5 file and restore model easily as below

```
model.save('model_vgg16.h5')
model = load_model('model_vgg16.h5')
```

Another way where you can save and restore using JSON as below

```
# Save the model

model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

model.save_weights("model.h5")

#Load the model

json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
```